# Закрытие модального окна при переходе на следующее м. окно

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
    self.btnrrr = QPushButton(self) 
    self.btnrrr.setText("Продолжить")
    self.btnrrr.clicked.connect(self.contin)
    layoutrrr.addWidget(self.btnrrr, 5, 2)

    self.btnrrr1 = QPushButton(self) 
    self.btnrrr1.setText("Отмена")
    self.btnrrr1.clicked.connect(self.reject)
    layoutrrr.addWidget(self.btnrrr1, 5, 1)

def getResult(self):
    return self.titleEdit.text()


def contin(self):
    self.contin = Window2()
    self.contin.exec()
```

При нажатии кнопки `"Продолжить"` я перехожу к следующему модальному окну `Window2`, но при этом открытым остаётся 1 м. окно `Window1`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно при переходе на 2-ое окно закрыть 1-ое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.btnrrr = QPushButton(self) 
        self.btnrrr.setText("Продолжить")
        self.btnrrr.clicked.connect(self.accept) 
        #QDialog.accept() закроет текущее окно, а exec вернет QDialog.Accepted

        self.btnrrr1 = QPushButton(self) 
        self.btnrrr1.setText("Отмена")
        self.btnrrr1.clicked.connect(self.reject)
```

Показываем окно MyDialog

```
mydialog = MyDialog()
if mydialog.exec() == QDialog.Accepted:
    # К этому моменту MyDialog будет закрыт    
    contin = Window2()
    contin.exec()
```